# Triple Vlookup in 3 columns

Tags: excel

Hi im seeking for help please check the attachment im trying to get the result to column b i am wandering if possible to vlookup column a to column C, D and E if found in column C answer will be january if not found then it will vlookup to D if found then answer should be Feb. if not found then it will search to column E

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't want to actually look up a a value from your to-searchable columns, you don't need vlookup but only to check which column your SKU can be found in.

Enter this code into B2:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C:C,A2)>0,C$1,IF(COUNTIF(D:D,A2)>0,D$1,IF(COUNTIF(E:E,A2)>0,E$1,"not found")))
```

Then copy cell B2 to B3:B18

Comment: thank you this is great i focus my mind solving this trough vlookup